# Limit the number of messages processed by a queue triggered frunction

Tags: azure, message-queue, azure-functions

I have a queue triggered function that POSTs to a server. I want to limit the number of posts made to the server to 1 post/ every 3 seconds. Is there a way to do this? If so, how?

Comment: Yes. Please try setting the nextvisibletime as suggested by the post @Mikhail pointed.

Comment: I had to use a combination of nextvisibletime and setting queues.batchSize to 1